# How to parse a product type partially

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

```hs
data Config = Config {
    a :: Bool,
    b :: Type1,
    c :: Type2
}

pA :: Parser Bool

pB :: Parser Type1

pC :: Parser Type2

pConfig :: Parser Config
pConfig = Config <$> pA <*> pB <*> pC

opts :: ParserInfo Config
opts = info (pConfig <**> helper)
       (fullDesc <> progDesc "My CLI" <> header "CLI executable")

main :: IO()
main = do
       (Config a b c) <- execParser opts
-- Populate a default config using a b c values
```

Is it possible to parse a product type partially? Config is a product type with member a, b and c and assume this comes from a library, so I cannot redefine this. I only want to parse a and b without caring about c. But, since a "Parser Config" can only have a construction like below

```hs
Config <$> pA <*> pB <*> pC
```

due to being a product type, if I do not give a "pC" it errors out. How to correctly handle this scenario?

Comment: Make a `Parser Config'` and define `Config'` to only have `a` and `b` and then have an `f :: Config' -> Config` that fills the c value with a default...

Comment: You need to provide *some* `pC`, but that doesn't have to be something that parses any actual string; it could simply be a hard-coded constant parser like `pC = pure someValueOfType2`.

Comment: @chepner I tried that but with the types involved I could not get it to work or may be I did not try hard enough with that approach.

Comment: @Bakuriu I have something similar at the moment and it does work. I was wondering if there is a cleaner approach already provided that somehow I am missing. I did try going through the docs..

Comment: In the worst possible scenario, `pC = pure (error "unparsed Type2")` could be used. I'd try other approaches first, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Config <$> pA <*> pB <*> pC` notation doesn’t care that `Config` is a constructor; you could have used any function of type `Bool -> Type1 -> Type2 -> Config`.  If you don’t want to parse a `Type2`, you could use any function of type `Bool -> Type1 -> Config`.

```hs
config' :: Bool -> Type1 -> Config
config' a b c = Config a b someDefaultType2

pConfig :: Parser Config
pConfig = config' <$> pA <*> pB
```

Equivalently, you stick with the `Config` constructor but connect a `pure` value instead of a parser to its third argument.

```hs
pConfig :: Parser Config
pConfig = Config <$> pA <*> pB <*> pure someDefaultType2
```

(Either way, you do need to have *some* way of providing a value of `Type2`, if you want to get a `Config` out.)

Comment: Thank you. I went with the second approach to make it work. I had tried that approach but I think something I must have messed with the types when I tried it first time.